# How can I use a short key to automatic math mode all rows of a table in tabularray package?

Tags: tabularray

I am trying make this table. My code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{diagbox}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{ninecolors}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{tblr}{
            colspec={|c|c|},row{1}={olive9},
        } \hline \text { Interval } & \text { Frequency } \\
        \hline $ \left[a_1 ; a_2\right) $ & $ n_1 $ \\
        {$ \left[a_2 ; a_3\right) $} & $ n_2 $ \\
        $ \ldots $ & $ \ldots $ \\
        {$ \left[a_m ; a_{m+1}\right) $} & $ n_m $ \\
        \hline & $ n $ \\
        \hline 
    \end{tblr}
    \caption{}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

In each row of the table, I use `$$`. How can I use a short key, e.g `\newcolumntype{C}{>{$\displaystyle}c<{$}}` to all mathmode of the table to remove all `$$` in rows?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `cells={mode=imath}` to change all cells to inline math mode (or use `dmath` to get display style math):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{diagbox}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{ninecolors}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{tblr}{
      colspec={cc},
      row{1}={olive9},
      vlines,
      hline{1,2,Y,Z} = {solid},
      cells={mode=dmath},
      row{1}={mode=text}
    } 
      Interval & Frequency\\
      \left[a_1 ; a_2\right)  &  n_1  \\
      \left[a_2 ; a_3\right)  &  n_2  \\
      \ldots  &  \ldots  \\
      \left[a_m ; a_{m+1}\right) &  n_m  \\
      &  n  \\ 
    \end{tblr}
    \caption{}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please explain for me this line `hline{1,2,Y,Z} = {solid}` and how can I use `dmath`?

Comment: The line `hline{1,2,Y,Z} = {solid}` will automatically insert horizontal lines for the first two and last two rows so you don't need all the `\hlines` in the code. You can use dmath as in `cells={mode=dmath}` (but for your example I doubt this will make much difference)

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: @JohnPaulPeter You're welcome! You could simplify your table further by using `row{1}={mode=text}` so you don't need the `\text{...}` in your first row